# Экранировать вложенные кавычки на Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Уже долго мучаюсь над проблемой. Имеются строки примерно такого формата:
registrationNumber:""074-р""
registrationNumber:"074"-р"
registrationNumber:""07"4-р""
После двоеточия наружные кавычки всегда имеются, количество вложенных кавычек может быть произвольным. Никак не могу реализовать способ экранировать кавычки, вложенные в основные. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а для чего вы хотите их экранировать и чем вы хотите их экранировать обратным слешом \?

Comment: обратным слешем, дело в том, что только, как выяснилось только в таком формате(registrationNumber:"\"074-р\"") сервер принимает данные. Причины сказать не могу, выяснил эмпирическим путем.

Comment: Заменить номером символа, не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде можно так.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "egistrationNumber:\"074\"-р\"";
        System.out.println(s);

        String replacedStr = s.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");

        System.out.println(replacedStr);
    }

}
```

ouput:

```
egistrationNumber:"074"-р"
egistrationNumber:\"074\"-р\"
```

**UDP:**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arrays = {
                "registrationNumber:\"\"074-р\"\"",
                "registrationNumber:\"074\"-р\"",
                "registrationNumber:\"\"07\"4-р\"\"",
        };
        Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile("(.+:)\"(.+)\"");
        for (String string : arrays) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String result = matcher.group(2).replace("\"", "\\\"");
                String newString = matcher.group(1) + "\"" + result + "\"";
                System.out.println("NewString: " + newString);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Не найден: " + string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ouput:

```
NewString: registrationNumber:"\"074-р\""
NewString: registrationNumber:"074\"-р"
NewString: registrationNumber:"\"07\"4-р\""
```

См. [демо на Java онлайн](https://ideone.com/7woUev).

Comment: Спасибо, но в этом случае экранируются все кавычки, а некой сущности, которая проверяет строку, нужно чтобы наружные кавычки остались неэкранированными. Вот так: egistrationNumber:"074\"-р", либо вот так: registrationNumber:"\"074-р\""

Comment: Регулярка для замены всех кавычек кавычками с обратным слешем не нужна. ``.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"")`` = `.replace("\"", "\\\"")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew попробуйте запустить, получится просто `egistrationNumber:\074\-р\`

Comment: @МДмитрий хорошо, сейчас попробую, может получится :)

Comment: @МДмитрий обновил код, возможно то что вам нужно, хотя возможно решение и не самое лучшее

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень помогли:)

Comment: @МДмитрий не за что